# Translating choices in Django without using loops?

Tags: python, django

I'm absolutely new in Python and I'm curious if given:

```
ENROLLMENT_STATUS = (
                         (1, 'Enrolled'),
                         (2, 'Promoted'),
                         (3, 'Dropped'),
                         (4, 'Failed'),
                     )
```

I could translate an integer 1..4 to its str counterpart without using a loop such as:

```
for i in Enrollment.ENROLLMENT_STATUS:
    if i[0] == self.enrollment_status:
        status = i[1]
        break
```

Thanks for everybody's help.

Regards,
Chad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert them to dictionary like this

```
try:
    {k: v for k, v in ENROLLMENT_STATUS}[self.enrollment_status]
except ValueError:
    raise # or whatever
```

or like this:

```
try:
    dict(ENROLLMENT_STATUS)[self.enrollment_status]
except ValueError:
    raise # or whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method, like this:

```
self.get_enrollment_status_display()
```

It will print `Enrolled` if the status was `1`, and so on.